# PHP How to add two list of decimal together

Tags: php, decimal

```
public function Encrypt($message)
    {
        $character = str_split($message);
        $encrypted = '';

        foreach ($character as $character)
        {
            $encrypted .= (ord($character). '.');

        }
       return $encrypted; 
    }
```

I use that code to generate ASCII numbers. Example of the result that I generated

`$a = 1.2.4.3.4.3`
`$b = 1.4.3.2.4.3`

Then I want both together (1+1,2+4,4+3,3+2,4+4,3+3) then the result is

```
$c = 2.6.7.5.8.6
```

Is it possible to do that ? Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Do you mean if you get a number like 2.4 you want to add 2 + 4 to get 6?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the list of numbers you get and how you want to add them up?

Comment: no i mean i use that code to generate 2 list of number example 1st > 2.5 and 2nd 2.7 i want to add 2+2 and 5+7 then the result is 4.12

Comment: Why don't you just add 2.5 + 2.7 to get 5.2?

Comment: because the list i generated is very long and i don't know how to sum both together

Comment: @undefined     yea my main idea is to add both block that separated by . see my calculation part

Comment: Would your lists be something like $a = 1.2.4.3.4.3 and $b = 1.4.3.2.4.3? Then you want to add like 1+1, then 2+4, etc..? I think you need to rewrite your question. It's not very clear, and the code doesn't help much. We need to see what your lists are and how they should end up after being added.

Comment: @Pierre-EmmanuelLevesque   yes correct and the result that i want is   $c = 2.6.7.5.8.6     is it possible ?

Comment: You do realise this is a poor way to **encrypt** text, don't you?

Comment: @hd1   hmmm... yea i know but since i am web designer and developer this is 1st time i do this stuff in php. I know its poor way but i am trying .. this is my 1st time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible:

```
$a = '1.2.4.3.4.3';
$b = '1.4.3.2.4.3';


$result = join('.', array_map(
    function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; },
    explode('.', $a),
    explode('.', $b)
));


var_dump($result);
```

Explanation:

1. split by `.`
2. summarize
3. join back

Ideone: http://ideone.com/uzBVed

Comment: do you know how to hide that var_dump($result) i don't want it to show in my site

Comment: @Adrian Halim: well, you use the `backspace` key on your keyboard and delete it from the file.

Comment: @Adrian Halim: are you sure? Just for a second: it was me who wrote it, so there is a chance I understand how it works ;-D

Comment: ah sorry my bad i done it at wrong place .. sorry its working.. i change it at my other page and run the other page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a function like this?

```
function add_number_strings($a, $b) {
    $a_arr = explode('.', $a);
    $b_arr = explode('.', $b); 
    $c_arr = array();

    for ($i=0; $i<count($a_arr); $i++) {    
        $c_arr[] = $a_arr[$i] + $b_arr[$i];
    }

    return implode('.', $c_arr);
}

// Testing
$a = '1.12.9.4.3.2.1';
$b = '2.3.2.4.3.2.1';

$c = add_number_strings($a, $b);

var_dump($c); // should be 3.15.11.8.6.4.2
```